# How to make images aligned horizontally, but align clickable images below each image

Tags: html, css

I've been looking for a question like this but I was unable to find one. I'm trying to make this horizontal instead of vertical:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
ghost<br class="newline">
<img src="resources/images/ghost.png" height=75 width=75>
<br class="newline">
<a href="http://instagram.com/ghost2000_" target=blank><img src="resources/images/instagram.png" height=20 width=20>
<a href="https://twitter.com/_ghost2000" target=blank><img src="resources/images/twitter.png" height=20 width=20>
<a href="https://twitter.com/_ghost2000" target=blank><img src="resources/images/soundcloud.png" height=20 width=25><br class="newline">
tshima<br class="newline">
<img src="resources/images/tshima.png" height=75 width=75>
<br class="newline">
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/ifinallyfigureditout/_" target=blank><img src="resources/images/instagram.png" height=20 width=20>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/tshimashimatshima/" target=blank><img src="resources/images/facebook.png" height=20 width=20>
<a href="https://soundcloud.com/cheatar1" target=blank><img src="resources/images/soundcloud.png" height=20 width=25>
<a href="https://tshima.bandcamp.com/" target=blank><img src="resources/images/bandcamp.png" height=20 width=20><br class="newline">
zero<br class="newline">
<img src="resources/images/zero.jpg" height=75 width=75>
<br class="newline">
<a href="http://instagram.com/sg_zero" target=blank><img src="resources/images/instagram.png" height=20 width=20>
<a href="https://soundcloud.com/zer0" target=blank><img src="resources/images/soundcloud.png" height=20 width=25><br class="newline">
vyrax<br class="newline">
<img src="resources/images/vyrax.jpg" height=75 width=75>
<br class="newline">
n0kia !<br class="newline">
<img src="resources/images/n0kia.jpg" height=75 width=75>
<br class="newline">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll need to do is slightly modify your HTML so that each of the sub-images are **grouped** with the main image inside a parent `<div>` container. I've gone with a class of `artist` in my example. Then simply set the `artist` class to **[`float: left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)**:

```
.artist {
  float: left;
}
```

Note that you'll no longer need the `<br>` lines for these `<div>` separators, and that you'll probably also want to tweak the `width` for each of your sub-images.

Also, don't forget to close your `<a>` tags with `</a>` after your images! Otherwise the links will 'leak' through, and you'll end up with invalid markup!

Fixing this up gives you the following code
(which can be copy-pasted and work with your own images):

```css
.artist {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="artist">
  ghost
  <br class="newline">
  <img src="resources/images/ghost.png" height=75 width=75>
  <br class="newline">
  <a href="http://instagram.com/ghost2000_" target=blank><img src="resources/images/instagram.png" height=20 width=20></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/_ghost2000" target=blank><img src="resources/images/twitter.png" height=20 width=20></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/_ghost2000" target=blank><img src="resources/images/soundcloud.png" height=20 width=25></a>
</div>

<div class="artist">
  tshima
  <br class="newline">
  <img src="resources/images/tshima.png" height=75 width=75>
  <br class="newline">
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ifinallyfigureditout/_" target=blank><img src="resources/images/instagram.png" height=20 width=20></a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/tshimashimatshima/" target=blank><img src="resources/images/facebook.png" height=20 width=20></a>
  <a href="https://soundcloud.com/cheatar1" target=blank><img src="resources/images/soundcloud.png" height=20 width=25></a>
  <a href="https://tshima.bandcamp.com/" target=blank><img src="resources/images/bandcamp.png" height=20 width=20></a>
</div>

<div class="artist">
  zero
  <br class="newline">
  <img src="resources/images/zero.jpg" height=75 width=75>
  <br class="newline">
  <a href="http://instagram.com/sg_zero" target=blank><img src="resources/images/instagram.png" height=20 width=20></a>
  <a href="https://soundcloud.com/zer0" target=blank><img src="resources/images/soundcloud.png" height=20 width=25></a>
</div>

<div class="artist">
  vyrax
  <br class="newline">
  <img src="resources/images/vyrax.jpg" height=75 width=75>
</div>

<div class="artist">
  n0kia !<br class="newline">
  <img src="resources/images/n0kia.jpg" height=75 width=75>
</div>
```

And replacing the relative images with absolutely-referenced images looks like this:

```css
.artist {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="artist">
  ghost
  <br class="newline">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=75 width=75>
  <br class="newline">
  <a href="http://instagram.com/ghost2000_" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=20></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/_ghost2000" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=20></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/_ghost2000" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=25></a>
</div>

<div class="artist">
  tshima
  <br class="newline">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=75 width=75>
  <br class="newline">
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ifinallyfigureditout/_" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=20></a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/tshimashimatshima/" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=20></a>
  <a href="https://soundcloud.com/cheatar1" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=25></a>
  <a href="https://tshima.bandcamp.com/" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=20></a>
</div>

<div class="artist">
  zero
  <br class="newline">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=75 width=75>
  <br class="newline">
  <a href="http://instagram.com/sg_zero" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=20></a>
  <a href="https://soundcloud.com/zer0" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=25></a>
</div>

<div class="artist">
  vyrax
  <br class="newline">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=75 width=75>
</div>

<div class="artist">
  n0kia !<br class="newline">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=75 width=75>
</div>
```

Note that you'll probably want to space them apart a little, which can be done with `margin-right` on each of the `artist` classes. Note that you'll probably not want it on the very last artist, so you'll instead want to target. This can be achieved by adding the rule to `.artist:not(:last-of-type)`.

This combines the pseudo-selectors **[`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)** and **[`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)**, so that every artist **apart** from the last one has the rule applied, as can be seen in the following:

```css
.artist {
  float: left;
}

.artist:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="artist">
  ghost
  <br class="newline">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=75 width=75>
  <br class="newline">
  <a href="http://instagram.com/ghost2000_" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=20></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/_ghost2000" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=20></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/_ghost2000" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=25></a>
</div>

<div class="artist">
  tshima
  <br class="newline">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=75 width=75>
  <br class="newline">
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ifinallyfigureditout/_" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=20></a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/tshimashimatshima/" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=20></a>
  <a href="https://soundcloud.com/cheatar1" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=25></a>
  <a href="https://tshima.bandcamp.com/" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=20></a>
</div>

<div class="artist">
  zero
  <br class="newline">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=75 width=75>
  <br class="newline">
  <a href="http://instagram.com/sg_zero" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=20></a>
  <a href="https://soundcloud.com/zer0" target=blank><img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=20 width=25></a>
</div>

<div class="artist">
  vyrax
  <br class="newline">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=75 width=75>
</div>

<div class="artist">
  n0kia !<br class="newline">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" height=75 width=75>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How would I go by adding space between them?

Comment: You'll probably want to give them a consistent `width` first, and then you'd be looking to apply something like `margin-right: 20px` to `.artist`. You'll also want to prevent the last one from having it applied. I've just updated my answer to cover that :)